# Equivalence of total boundedness and relative compactness in Polish spaces.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, polish-spaces

> Let $E$ be a Polish space. A set $A\subset E$ is totally bounded if and only if $A$ is relatively compact.

First we suppose $A$ is totally bounded. Since $\overline A$ is closed and $E$ is complete, $\overline A$ is complete. Let $x$ be the limit of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $y_1,\ldots, y_n\in A$ so that $A\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(y_i,\varepsilon/2)$. Choose $N$ such that $d(x_n,x)<\varepsilon/2$ and let $j$ be such that $x_N\in B(y_j,\varepsilon/2)$. Then $$d(x,y_j)<d(x,x_n)+d(x_n,y_j)<\varepsilon,$$ so that $x\in B(x,y_j)$. It follows that $\overline A$ is totally bounded, and thus compact.

I am a bit unsure of this since I did not use the separability of $E$. I also do not see how to show the converse. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separability is not required. The equivalence is true in any complete metric space. For the converse note that $\overset {-} A$ can be covered by  a finite number of balls of radius $\epsilon$ (because it is compact and it is covered by all balls of radius $\epsilon)$. Hence $\overset {-} A$ is totally bounded. Any subset of a totally bounded set is also totally bounded, so $A$ is totally bounded.

Proof of the fact that if $A \subset B$ and $B$ is totally bounded the $A$ is totally bounded: cover $B$ by balls $B(b_i,\epsilon /2), 1\leq i \leq n$. Without loss of generality assume that each of these balls has non-empty intersection with $A$. Let $a_i \in A\cap B(b_i,\epsilon /2)$. You can now verify that $A$ is covered by the balls $B(a_i,\epsilon)$.